# How to load xml document in property grid

Tags: c#, winforms

How to load xml document in property grid and display the xml tags as properties in property grid

For the above question I got answer(by Marc Gravell code) in property grid but because of expandable object converter I'm getting "+" for all properties I need to remove it ,how to remove

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a simple request; you would have to write a wrapper class (for an `XmlNode`) that has a custom `TypeConverter` (alternatively: `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`, but `TypeConverter` is simplest). Then write a custom `PropertyDescriptor` (or several) to represent the fake properties. Assuming `TypeConverter`, override `GetProperties` to return the artificial properties (for values or sub-nodes).

It would be easier to build it upwards from a `TreeView`...

---

OK; this is **not** easy; this is a very untested **start** point - crude and barely functional, but here it is anyway.

For more reference on what is happening here, look in particular at `PropertyDescriptor` which simulates properties, and `TypeConverter` which *provides* the properties (although there are other options for this).

Some other articles that may help:

- [Data binding dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data)
- [Properties generated at runtime (PropertyGrid.SelectedObject)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091888/properties-generated-at-runtime-propertygrid-selectedobject)
- [How to display a dynamic object in property grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491556/how-to-display-a-dynamic-object-in-property-grid)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace DemoApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<xml a=\"b\"><c>d<e f=\"g\">h</e>i</c>j</xml>");
            using (var grid = new PropertyGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                SelectedObject = new XmlNodeWrapper(doc.DocumentElement)})
            using (var form = new Form { Controls = {grid}})
            {
                Application.Run(form);
            }
        }
    }
}
[TypeConverter(typeof(XmlNodeWrapperConverter))]
class XmlNodeWrapper
{
    private readonly XmlNode node;
    public XmlNodeWrapper(XmlNode node) { this.node = node; }
    class XmlNodeWrapperConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            List<PropertyDescriptor> props = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
            XmlElement el = ((XmlNodeWrapper)value).node as XmlElement;
            if (el != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute attr in el.Attributes)
                {
                    props.Add(new XmlNodeWrapperPropertyDescriptor(attr));
                }
            }
            foreach (XmlNode child in ((XmlNodeWrapper)value).node.ChildNodes)
            {
                props.Add(new XmlNodeWrapperPropertyDescriptor(child));
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props.ToArray(), true);
        }
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(string)
                ? ((XmlNodeWrapper)value).node.InnerXml
                : base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
    class XmlNodeWrapperPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private static readonly Attribute[] nix = new Attribute[0];
        private readonly XmlNode node;
        public XmlNodeWrapperPropertyDescriptor(XmlNode node) : base(GetName(node), nix)
        {
            this.node = node;
        }
        static string GetName(XmlNode node)
        {
            switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Attribute: return "@" + node.Name;
                case XmlNodeType.Element: return node.Name;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment: return "<!-- -->";
                case XmlNodeType.Text: return "(text)";
                default: return node.NodeType + ":" + node.Name;
            }
        }
        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }
        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            node.Value = (string)value;
        }
        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return !IsReadOnly;
        }
        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            SetValue(component, "");
        }
        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get {
                switch (node.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        return typeof(XmlNodeWrapper);
                    default:
                        return typeof(string);
                }
            }
        }
        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get {
                switch (node.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        return false;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    return new XmlNodeWrapper(node);
                default:
                    return node.Value;
            }
        }
        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return typeof(XmlNodeWrapper); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @subbiah allow me to emphasise - runtime pseudo-properties is a tricky  corner of .NET; only look at this if you are really confident in .NET, and ideally have *comsumed* `System.ComponentModel` before (as *authoring* it tends to require a working knowledge of what is going on)]

Comment: if you know any materials related to this please, suggest me